# How to get changes from other users in VS Code from TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2015, azure-repos

This question is for building Angular application in VS Code.

My team has been coding in VS2015 and using Microsoft TFS for version control (Please note that our code is within the company firewall, on a local TFS build server and not on Gits repository). For Angular, I installed VS Code and Azure Repos plugin for TFS.

Once Work-space is setup, I can see the files (I downloaded the files from VS2015 on local machine) but they all show as "Untracked" changes - why? These are checked in files.

Also, when a colleague checks-in files from their VS Code instance, my VS Code doesn't get it.

What is that I am missing here?

Comment: You are missing your workspace mapping - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/create-work-workspaces?view=azure-devops

Comment: I already have workspace mapping that's how I connect VS2015 to TFS.

Comment: Is everything mapped? I didn't downvote you btw

Comment: Thanks for your response, appreciate it :-) downvote is not a problem, I am just starting with Angular and its structure, in every way, is very different from traditional programming I have been doing for years, hence had these basic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue (or a workaround). Posting my solution for any newbie facing the same issue:

- Please note that my code is not in GITS or any remote repository, it is in Team Server hosted in the company data center.
- I have a workspace created in VS2015 via which I mapped my Angular code and downloaded it on local machine.

**VS Code Settings:**

- Make sure you have Azure Repos extension installed.
- Go to File->Preferences->Settings (make sure User settings tab is selected)-> Extensions-> Azure Repos extension:
  Provide the values for following fields:

   (a) Tfvc: Location 
  Example value for VS2015: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\tf.exe
   (b) Tfvc: Proxy
    Example (this should be your team server name): https://dataCenter.myCompany.com:9100/tfs

  (c) Tfvc: Restrict Workspace (this is optional, use only if needed)
     Check the box
- Goto View->Command Palette-> type Team: Signin, provide username and password.
- Goto File->Open folder-> select the folder mapped via VS2015.
- Once the folder is open, you will see all files inside the folder. Go to File->Save Workspace As and give it a name.

  Now you should be able to see any changes done by you in either VS2015 or VS code. Check-in should reflect the changes for you and other users connected to the code.

Previous Mistake: I realized that I was using Gits:Initialize Repository (as advised on various sites) which was causing all the trouble of "Untracked" changes and other users' changes not reflecting in my code.

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.